# Show $(a,b)$ is in the equivalence relation $L_s$ iff $(ap,bp)$ is in $L_{s/p}$ where p is a congruence on semigroup S

Tags: congruences, equivalence-relations, semigroups

So the question that I'm struggling with is as follows:

Let S be an arbitrary semigroup, and define an equivalence relation $L_S$ on S by

$(a, b) ∈ L_S$ iff $S^1 a = S^1b$.

Let $ρ$ be a congruence on S such that $ρ ⊆ L_S$.

Show that $(a, b) ∈ L_S$ in S iff $(aρ, bρ) ∈ L_{S/ρ}$ in
$S/ρ$.

I believe that I have the forward direction but I'm not sure so firstly is this correct?

$(a, b) ∈ L_S$ and $ρ ⊆ L_S$ implies that $aρb$

$\Rightarrow aρ=bρ$

$\Rightarrow (S/ρ)(aρ)=(S/ρ)(bρ)$

$\Rightarrow (aρ, bρ) ∈ L_{S/ρ}$

For the reverse proof I am completely stumped! I have tried plugging away at a few things and proof by contradiction but nothing seemed to lead the the answer I was hoping for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is incorrect. Indeed $\rho \subseteq \mathcal{L}_S$ means $(a,b) \in \rho$ implies $(a,b) \in \mathcal{L}_S$ (and not the other way around, as you wrote).
Anyway, the implication
$$
(a, b) \in \mathcal{L}_S \implies (a\rho, b\rho) \in \mathcal{L}_{S/\rho} 
$$
is true without any assumption on $\rho$. Indeed let $\rho: S \to S/\rho$ be the quotient map. Then $(a, b) \in \mathcal{L}_S$ means that $S^1a = S^1b$. This implies that $(S\rho)^1(a\rho) = (S^1a)\rho = (S^1b)\rho = (S\rho)^1 (b\rho)$, that is $(a\rho, b\rho) \in \mathcal{L}_{S/\rho}$.

Now, for the opposite implication
$$
(a\rho, b\rho) \in \mathcal{L}_{S/\rho} \implies (a, b) \in \mathcal{L}_S  
$$
your hypothesis is required. If $(a\rho, b\rho) \in \mathcal{L}_{S/\rho}$ there exists some $c, d$ in $S^1$ such that $(c\rho)(a\rho) = b\rho$ and $(d\rho)(b\rho) = a\rho$. It follows that $(ca)\rho = b\rho$ and $(db)\rho = a\rho$. Therefore $(ca, b) \in \rho$ and $(db, a) \in \rho$. Since $\rho \subseteq \mathcal{L}_S$, one gets $(ca, b) \in \mathcal{L}_S$ and $(db, a) \in \mathcal{L}_S$. It follows that $S^1b = S^1ca \subseteq S^1a$ and $S^1a = S^1db \subseteq S^1b$, whence $S^1a = S^1b$ as required.

Comment: A few questions as I'm struggling to understand this. Firstly, on the "opposite implication" proof when you get that  $(ca, b) \in \mathcal{L}_S$ and $(a, db) \in \mathcal{L}_S$ can you just say that therefore $(a, b) \in \mathcal{L}_S$ by transitivity of $\rho$?

Comment: And secondly I'm not really sure what the quotient map is- is it a specific congruence? I think that I read that $\rho$ natural maps $S \to S/\rho$ but I'm again not too sure

Comment: How do you want to use transitivity in this case? $ca$ is not equal to $db$.

Comment: About your second question: yes $\rho$ natural maps $S$ onto $S/\rho$.

Comment: After reviewing the definition of transitivity and your comment I get my mistake in my first question but I'm still struggling with understanding the forward proof. Do I not need to show that $(S/\rho)^1(a) =  (S/\rho)^1 (b)$ for $(a\rho, b\rho) \in \mathcal{L}_{S/\rho}$ rather than what you have shown or are they equivalent?